# In RSpec I want to replace argument to a method call

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

My app is using OpenURI's `open()` method, to fetch a web page.

In my spec I want to be able to replace the URL passed in open to the path of a local file.

So when calling `open('http://www.google.com')` I want to switch that url to `/path/to/file`.

Is there a build-in way to do this in RSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think rspec provide anything to achieve this. You're better off adding a parameter to the method that invokes `open()` in your application. This will make the code reusable.

If the application code cannot be modified, you could try to overwrite the `open()` method to substitute the parameter in your rspec script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to write tests against remote URLs, I'd suggest taking a look at the following:

WebMock: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

VCR: https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr